# Will a master's in math from the University of Vienna help or hurt my Ph.D. prospects?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics

My end goal is to become a professor of either mathematics or philosophy. I haven't made up my mind which. Thus, I plan to get a master's degree in math, specializing in logic, in order to continue my education without committing to either discipline. More generally, I suppose my question is: is this a sensible plan, and is the University of Vienna a good place to carry it out?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it might be otherwise. The university has a very rich history and has produced many Nobel prize winners.

Answer (score 1):

Kurt Gödel is an alumnus of University of Vienna, and would be a pretty hard act to follow, but at the intersection of math and philosophy he has few peers.

I think your plan is perfectly reasonable, though if you don't speak and write German, you might want to address that. Maybe not essential today, I guess.

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Vienna) on the university is informative, of course.

Comment: There’s also the Vienna Circle! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Circle

Comment: That's at least three generations of researchers ago. Sorry, but this legacy really doesn't matter anymore for anything but the university's public image.